# Alternative to Dynamic Variables?

Tags: r

I have a large dataset that is represented as "importdata" and it's structured as:

```
| Date | Qobs | Qobsmodel |
```

So it's a table broken into Date, Observed Flow, and Modelled Flow (Hydrology).

This data is in a daily time step over multiple years.  However this script I'm using needs to break them down into yearly datasets and then perform an analysis on each "year".  Therefore, I've been using Dynamic Variables (having the script generate it's own variables and using those) to have each section of the dataset broken down.

```
for (i in 1:numberyears) {
  yearstartpaste <- paste(yearsimport[i],"-01-01", sep = "")

  yearendpaste <- paste(yearsimport[i]+1,"-01-01", sep = "")

  variablename <- paste("year",yearsimport[i],"data", sep = "")

  assign(variablename, 
         flowdatadf[flowdatadf$Date >= yearstartpaste & flowdatadf$Date < yearendpaste])
}
```

Where "numberofyears" is the total number of years between start year and end year, "yearsimport" is the years I need broken down in an array, and "flowdatadf" being the full flow dataset.

Later on, I call the dataset broken down in the following manner.

```
for (i in 1:numberyears) {
  variablename <- paste("year",yearsimport[i],"data", sep = "")

  maxflow[i] <- max(eval(parse(text = variablename))$Qobsmodel, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

From what I can tell, this is a very sloppy way of coding in R.  Reading other stackexchange posts regarding dynamic variables, I was wondering if anyone had a better idea/solution to my methodology?

Some suggests using a data frame with another variable, but I don't see how this works in my case where my dynamic variables need to deal with arrays/tables.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Imo for the edit.  I guess I messed up a bit in formatting.

Comment: You should never use `eval(parse())`. If you find that you need it, you should reconsider your approach. Often you can use a list instead. Look into `split` or even better learn to write functions and use the "split-apply-combine" approach which is implemented in a number of functions.

Comment: E.g., if you want to calculate the maximum flow per year, you could use `aggregate`.

Comment: Thanks @Roland.  Yeah that was why I actually made this post, to find the proper approach because I'm fairly certain using "eval" is usually never a good idea.  I'll take a look at `aggregate`.